# go up to 3 level dephth in hibernate criterion

Tags: hibernate

i am using hibernate criterion for fetching results. Here with i provided demo design of my persistence class.

```
Class A{
private B b;
}
Class B{
private C c;
}
Class C{
private Long val;
}
```

assume these are the hibernate persistence classes i am not writing all annotations of mapping with database.

now my problem is i want to retrieve results of **Class A** according to the value of **Class C's val property**.

i tried to fetch it using,

```
Criteria c = Restrictions.eq("b.c.val", value);
List l = c.list;
```

it shows could not resolve property. i searched and came to know criteria wont work up to this much depth. i don't want shift to HQL. any idea??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(A.class)
    .createCriteria("b")
    .createCriteria("c")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("val", value));

List l = c.list;
```

Comment: Thanks Firo... its perfectly what i want.