# Hibernate Criteria `createAlias` "deep chaining": is it a bug?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am doing querying in MS SQL database with Hibernate 4.3.8, with Criteria. I found some strange behavior of Criteria.

If I do some "deep chaining" with `createAlias`, it will not work:

```
criteria.createAlias("user.supervision.supervisor", "uS");
```

Actually, according to a post of yesterday(sorry I didn't save it), Hibernate has no notion of "depth", as described in another question.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041656/go-up-to-3-level-dephth-in-hibernate-criterion). So I changed my code to:

```
criteria.createAlias("user", "u");
criteria.createAlias("u.supervision", "uSup");
criteria.createAlias("uSup.supervisor", "uS");
```

And it is working.

Is this an expected behavior, or some "hidden" rule that till now I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

It is the expected behavior. You can do it with aliases as you already did, or you can nest criteria as suggested in the answer of the question you linked to:

```
criteria
  .createCriteria("user")
  .createCriteria("supervision")
  .createCriteria("supervisor")
```